# Django/python and Apache Solr: pysolr or solrpy?

Tags: python, django, solr, pysolr

brand new on this forum and this is my first post!
At work we're starting a project which uses Apache Solr and i'm in charge of the frontend system (Django-based).

Our solr database isn't related to any other db engine nor to any models' class, so Haystack isn't good for us (since its strictly related to the models).

I was looking at http://code.google.com/p/pysolr/ and http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/

Basically, they're similar. I like more solrpy, since it uses POST requests and we can mask our users queries, but this makes its paginator harder to use (i guess..).
Other side, pysolr, thanks to the GET method, performs better (lower query timing), but so far i couldn't execute a query without getting a badrequest error.

Before choosing one, i wanted to ask the community any opinion. Users need to do only searches, our data is handled by a java process, no other db is used (except for storing user informations), and we need to use all solr features (faceting, highlight, word stopping, analyzers...). 
What will you choose? And why? Any good code example you can point me at? I was looking throu the haystack source to see how they did implement all...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have used 'solrpy', but encountered some problems with it.
Sunburnt is actually an interesting API:

https://github.com/tow/sunburnt/

Actively developed, and easy to use. Unfortunately it introduces some additional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I actually couldn't wait for this answer to come, so i figured out by myself (and i should have posted here, actually...). Sunburnt is the best api to use properly solr from python without the django model dependencies.